# Objective C - Quartz 2D finding line intersect

Tags: objective-c

I'm currently using CGContextMoveToPoint, CGContextAddLineToPoint & CGContextStrokePath to draw lines on a view.

Basically making a snake game that also allows user to move diagonally.

Is there a way to find when 2 lines that I draw intersect or do I have to manually calculate each lines and see if anything intersects?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the CG methods are somewhat CPU heavy, your best bet is to write a method that calculates an intersection point using basic geometry. Or use the [Sweep Line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm), it shouldn't be too hard.

EDIT: In fact, since you're making a snake game wherein blocks are laid out in a grid, you can just flag some of the blocks as *containing a snake/whatever* and if a block is about to be flagged twice, then you do whatever you wanted to do upon line intersection.